# Where to find a large text corpus?

Tags: dataset

I am looking for large (>1000) text corpus to download. Preferably with **world news** or some kind of **reports**. I have only found one with patents. Any suggestions?

Comment: This thread appears to be off topic.  See http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1032/data-sourcing-we-need-to-make-up-our-mind/1033#comment2001_1033.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about finding a data set, rather than doing statistical analysis

Comment: Well that's awkward, because this Q&A is really useful.

Comment: @guaka, please do not bump such old posts for such minor edits, especially a post that is closed. It is true that our style preference is not to have "thanks", but for something this minor, we'd just leave it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do not the Wikileaks texts suit you?

Comment: But how could I download them in .txt

Answer (score 6):

What about [wikinews](http://en.wikinews.org/wiki/Main_Page)? Here's the latest database dump I could find: http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwikinews/20111120/

You probably want the "All pages, current versions only."-version.

Comment: This no longer works.

Comment: dump link no longer works. dataset by region is small and outdated

Answer (score 6):

The reuters text corpus is a classic in the field, and can be found [here](http://www.daviddlewis.com/resources/testcollections/reuters21578/)

Comment: It's not the most interesting (or diverse) corpus. The license is also restrictive relative to Wikileaks (public domain US documents) or wikinews.

Comment: @ariddell i agree, but it is commonly used in introductory NLP examples, and its large enough to be useful in learning but small enough to be analysed on a good laptop.

Answer (score 3):

http://endb-consolidated.aihit.com/datasets.htm  contains 10K companies with textual descriptions

Comment: is currently outdated

Answer (score 1):

If recency is not an issue, you can try

http://www.infochimps.com/datasets/20-newsgroups-dataset-de-duped-version

and there are other many more similar dataset in infochimp depending on your budget.

Regards,
Andy.

Comment: This no longer works

Answer (score 1):

If you want precomputed n-grams, you could try the google books archive:

http://books.google.com/ngrams/datasets

Comment: how this one can be used?